# resource.id doesn't contain a definition for button and Layout

Tags: button, layout, xamarin.android

I created an Android project on Xamarin and  added a button in the layout but I'm having this error of **Resource.Id doesn't contain a definition for Button** when i create the button using **FindViewById** in the Activity.  Despite giving the an id to the button and layout using (android:id="@+id/btnShow"), I'm still having the error. I checked the Resource.Designer but could not find the aapt for the button.

Another issue that I faced is when I created a layout, gave it and defined it in an activity but the  **Resource.layout doesn't contain a definition for the layout**.

**However, other buttons and layouts can be defined in my activities**

Answer (score 0):

Actually this problem occurs when your ResourceDesigner.cs file has not yet mapped the file that you added to your resource directory(Xamarin Bug). The easiest way i would suggest to handle this situation is you comment the code you are trying to write and clean build your project and it will work like a charm. Good luck!

Comment: What Exactly did you do? try deleting the bin and obj files aswell and then revert @Palavi002

Comment: I commented the codes and cleaned the project. Then I uncommented the codes again. What do you mean by revert? @G.hakim

Comment: Comment the code clean the project then build it and then uncomment the code again

Comment: Post Your Code please